# Is it possible to copy an Azure Website?

Tags: azure

I want to copy an existing "Share" Mode "Dev" Website to another "Test" "Share" Mode Website. Is this possible? I know one can do this with SQL Azure DBs using a T-SQL command.

At the moment I:

1) Create new Website.

2) FTP across Dev Azure Website to Test Azure Website. This is fine, but seems longwinded from a network perspective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. This is probably more suited to [webmasters.se] or [sf]

Comment: Ok, I did not know about Webmasters, so thanks for this. However I am asking it here as I am sure that Azure developers will have come across this issue when porting to Azure. Also there are a lot more Azure folk here than on Webmasters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on what you want to do, but have you looked at using the Staging slot instead of creating a new website? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Comment: That is only available for standard websites ($$$). I think he is looking for a solution for "shared" websites.

Comment: Scenario: we need an identical copy (with attribute settings) to add as a failover instance in traffic manager.Are slots meant/adequate for this?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across a nice little feature:

1. **Create a new website**

   1. On "Configure"-tab: Enable "Edit in Visual Studio Online"
2. **On your existing site**

   1. Enable "Edit in Visual Studio Online" (if not already enabled)
   2. Click "Edit in Visual Studio Online" on "Dashboard"-tab
   3. Click "..." in Explorer and choose "Download workspace"
      [image: Download Workspace]
   4. Save the file to your desktop
3. **On your new site**

   1. Click "Edit in Visual Studio Online" on "Dashboard"-tab
   2. Delete "hostingstart.html"
   3. Drag-n-drop your "wwwroot.zip" file into the explorer
   4. Click the little icon at the very right
      [image: Extract All]
   5. Await magic!
   6. All your files are now copied to the new site
   7. Remember to delete "wwwroot.zip"

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to create a copy, not a deployment slot, it is now possible.

You can clone a web app though the azure portal, if you temporarily upgrade to a premium app service. [Image of where to find web app copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sO5N.png)

You can also copy an entire App Service though power shell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning

Answer (score 0):

I just used this https://github.com/SunBuild/azure-clone-webapps. It worked great, was fast and simple. Much better and more sustainable than paying Microsoft crazy amounts for this relatively simple task.