# Massive copy files from a web app site to another

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How would it be possible to load into a web app files from another webapp without needed to download a full copy locally?

we have a few sites (most on Shared pricing) where we need to load on request data from another site, application architecture requires this separation and "synchronization" only on request, is that possible to do without need of local download of all files?

I gave a look to:

Stack Overflow :: 
[How do I copy a website from one azure website to another (not deployment slots)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702997/how-do-i-copy-a-website-from-one-azure-website-to-another-not-deployment-slots)

Stack Overflow :: [Is it possible to copy an Azure Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520820/is-it-possible-to-copy-an-azure-website)

but neither helps. SiteReplicator seems to be too automatic (haven't been able to make it work) and backup doesn't allow granularity (90% os site needs to be sync, but 10% should not). and the download workspace on doesn't avoid the local loading,

what would be great, it would be a ftp2ftp connection, so i could mirror the needed folders and not the rest, but cdm through .scm.azurewebsites.net doesn't allow ftp (access denied)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Why can't you just deploy the same code to a different web app, via your associated version-control (e.g. github)? You're talking about trying to avoid downloading a full copy, but... wouldn't you already have a copy of your app either locally or in version control, which you used for initial deployment?

Comment: Are you cloning a web app in one resource group into the cloned web app in a different resource group?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, sorry I made a mistake in the title I may have give the wrong meaning, I do not want to clone the whole app, but about 90% of the contents on a system that is indeed running. Due application requirements those have to be on own WebApp (shared resources is not an option) and neither automatic (just on request).

Comment: @juvchan, not cloning web apps, but "injecting" 90% of its content on another

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service (Web App, Mobile App, API App etc) supports **App Cloning**, which gives users the ability to clone an existing Web App to a newly created app in a different region or in the same region.

[Azure App Service App Cloning Using Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-app-cloning-portal)

[Azure App Service App Cloning Using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-app-cloning)

**Important Note:** App cloning is currently only supported for **premium tier app service plans**.

To workaround this constraint, you can scale up the web app(s) you want to clone to Premium tier and then scale down to original tier after cloning is done.

Comment: yes, I know the cloning thing. Lets say a webApp is a kitchen, and among configurations, associated domains, SSL , backups plans and plenty others, it has a bunch of files in the "ftp" [lets call it the stuff in the fridge and the gadgets on the drawer]. What I would like is like to fell home in a new kitchen, I do not need to change the ceiling, the cooker or the fridge itself. Just want a magic-wand that takes all food and gadgets and place them in this new kitchen. Not really cloning my old kitchen, will not fit in new flat even same m2. Just my stuff, but avoiding moving boxes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised they still haven't added a slot copy function directly in Azure.  To answer David Makogon's question in an earlier comment, we have some large files that are excluded from our deployment process so simply deploying to an empty slot doesn't recreate all files needed for our application to start.  I figured out a roundabout solution from piecing together a few other guides.

1. Following this guide to install Azure Powershell and sign in to your Azure Account:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.6.0
2. Execute the following commands to get an app service plan and then create a new slot based on that app service plan.  Effectively cloning to a new slot.

$srcapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -Name "AppServiceName"

$destapp = New-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -Name "AppServiceName" -Slot "SlotName" -AppServicePlan "AppServicePlan" -SourceWebApp $srcapp

Note the resourcegroupname is not enclosed in quotes in the second command.

To rapidly create new instances of an existing app service.  I cloned it using the built in clone app service functionality in Azure.  Then used the above commands to create the deployment slot.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question and would be better to be added as a comment to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, I assume that you could leverage `Zip API` from [KUDU REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to download the specific folder/file as zip files from your source Web App, then expand the zipped files into the folders within your another Web App. Here is sample of using Zip REST API with PowerShell:

```html
$username = "`$website"
$password = "pwd"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

$apiUrl = "https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot"
$filePath = "C:\Temp\books.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Additonally, you could leverage [Azure WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-webjobs-resources) to run as background process in the context of your source Web App to periodically or manually invoke the Zip API for synchronizing content between your two Web Apps.

**Note:** You could leverage file system of your Web App as temp folder to store your zip files. For more details, you could refer to [Azure Web Apps File system](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#file-system).